# Writing a simple code validator

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I know that programming languages can be defined in EBNF which can be converted into regular expressions. Right now I am working on a very simple BASIC interpreter for a project. The code has to be entered in a gui which should validate the syntax to later transfer the code to an embedded system where it is executed.

I was googling to find an article or tutorial on writing a validator for this job but I could not really find such a thing. Is it just defining the regular expressions and try to match them?

Note: the GUI part is written in Java while the embedded code is written in C++.

Comment: I wouldn't try to do it in a regular expression. The classic approach would be to define lexicals and grammar in bison and yacc (gnu)

Comment: I added a note.

Comment: Even then it should be possible to glue in c-code. At least this approach would be to use an existing (pre-)solution proven in use over more than 20 years instead of ... well, let me quote "I had a problem, and used regular expressions to solve it. Now I have two problems" ;-)

Comment: you are right I'm having a look at jflex and antlr

Comment: I believe that coding a simple BASIC interpreter is much more difficult than what you believe. And it is less fun than e.g. coding a simple Lisp or Scheme interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial premise that an EBNF language description can be converted to regular expressions is incorrect. The set of languages that can be parsed with regular expressions is a subset of the set of languages that can be described in EBNF.
For example, it is impossible to write a regular expression to check if nested parentheses are balanced.

The best way to validate your language input is to write a parser for it. There are also parser generators (a-la yacc/bison) for Java.

Comment: And of course, the initial premise of the initial premise is also incorrect: not all programming languages can be described by EBNF, only those whose syntax is context-free can.

Answer (score 0):

Code validation should not only be [syntactical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29), but more importantly should take some of the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29), which is much harder. Read about [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference), etc...

For your project, did you consider embedding an existing interpreter (e.g. [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) or [Lua](http://lua.org/), etc...) inside your program?

If you want to write an interpreter, read about [domain specific languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language). See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/250740/40065) to a related question.